# Confusion about thread-safety

Tags: c++, c++11, thread-safety

I am new to the world of concurrency but from what I have read I understand the program below to be undefined in its execution. If I understand correctly this is not threadsafe as I am concurrently reading/writing both the shared_ptr and the counter variable in non-atomic ways.

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>


struct Inner {
    Inner() {
        t_ = std::thread([this]() {
            counter_ = 0;
            running_ = true;
            while (running_) {
                counter_++;
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
            }
        });
    }

    ~Inner() {
        running_ = false;
        if (t_.joinable()) {
            t_.join();
        }
    }


    std::uint64_t counter_;
    std::thread t_;
    bool running_;
};


struct Middle {

    Middle() {
        data_.reset(new Inner);
        t_ = std::thread([this]() {
            running_ = true;
            while (running_) {
                data_.reset(new Inner());
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
            }
        });
    }

    ~Middle() {
        running_ = false;
        if (t_.joinable()) {
            t_.join();
        }
    }

    std::uint64_t inner_data() {
        return data_->counter_;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<Inner> data_;
    std::thread t_;
    bool running_;
};

struct Outer {

    std::uint64_t data() {
        return middle_.inner_data();
    }

    Middle middle_;
};




int main() {

    Outer o;
    while (true) {
        std::cout << "Data: " << o.data() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My confusion comes from this:

1. Is the access to `data_->counter` safe in `Middle::inner_data`?
2. If thread A has a member `shared_ptr<T> sp` and decides to update it while thread B does `shared_ptr<T> sp = A::sp` will the copy and destruction be threadsafe? Or do I risk the copy failing because the object is in the process of being destroyed.

Under what circumstances (can I check this with some tool?) is undefined likely to mean `std::terminate`? I suspect something like the above happens in some of my production code but I cannot be certain as I am confused about 1 and 2 but this small program has been running for days since I wrote it and nothing happens.

Code can be checked here at https://godbolt.org/g/saHz94

Comment: "is undefined likely to mean `std::terminate`?" No, it means the program can do whatever it wants. This includes `std::terminate`ing, giving the wrong result, infinite loops or various other effects. The effect might change between compiler versions, flags, code changes and possibly even compilations. There is no reasoning about this code.

Comment: This might be what you're looking for
[#include <atomic>] [std::atomic<std::uint64_t> counter_;]

Comment: @aj.toulan Thanks for the suggestion, I am aware of atomic types, I am just slightly confused about what can happen in 1 write / multiple reader scenarios.

Comment: @arynaq #2 'atomic_shared_ptr<>' has thread-safe construction/copy but I'm not sure if you'll end up with a dangling reference on another thread during destruction. I'm pretty new to threading, so apologizes if that doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the access to data_->counter safe in Middle::inner_data?

No; it's a race condition.  According to the standard, it's undefined behavior anytime you allow unsynchronized access to the same variable from more than one thread, and at least one thread might possibly modify the variable.

As a practical matter, here are a couple of unwanted behaviors you might see:

1. The thread reading the value of counter_ reads an "old" value of counter (that rarely or never updates) due to different processor cores caching the variable independently of each other (using atomic_t would avoid this problem, because then the compiler would be aware that you are intending this variable to be accessed in an unsynchronized manner, and it would know to take precautions to prevent this problem)
2. Thread A might read the address that the `data_` shared_pointer points to and be just about to dereference the address and read from the `Inner` struct it points to, when Thread A gets kicked off the CPU by thread B.  Thread B executes, and during Thread B's execution, the old Inner struct gets deleted and the `data_` shared_pointer set to point to a new Inner struct.  Then Thread A gets back onto the CPU again, but since Thread A already has the old pointer value in memory, it dereferences the old value rather than the new one and ends up reading from freed/invalid memory.  Again, this is undefined behavior, so in principle anything could happen; in practice you're likely to see either no obvious misbehavior, or occasionally a wrong/garbage value, or possibly a crash, it depends.

> If thread A has a member shared_ptr sp and decides to update it
>   while thread B does shared_ptr sp = A::sp will the copy and
>   destruction be threadsafe? Or do I risk the copy failing because the
>   object is in the process of being destroyed.

If you're only retargeting the shared_ptrs themselves (i.e. changing them to point to different objects) and not modifying the T objects that they point to, that should be thread safe AFAIK.  But if you are modifying state of the T objects themselves (i.e. the `Inner` object in your example) that is not thread safe, since you could have one thread reading from the object while another thread is writing to it (deleting the object can be seen as a special case of writing to it, in that it definitely changes the object's state)

> Under what circumstances (can I check this with some tool?) is
>   undefined likely to mean std::terminate?

When you hit undefined behavior, it's very much dependent on the details of your program, the compiler, the OS, and the hardware architecture what will happen.  In principle, undefined behavior means anything (including the program running just as you intended!) can happen, but you can't rely on any particular behavior -- which is what makes undefined behavior so evil.

In particular, it's common for a multithreaded program with a race condition to run fine for hours/days/weeks and then one day the timing is just right and it crashes or computes an incorrect result.  Race conditions can be really difficult to reproduce for that reason.

As for when terminate() might be called, terminate() would be called if the the fault causes an error state that is detected by the runtime environment (i.e. it corrupts a data structure that the runtime environment does integrity checks on, such as, in some implementations, the heap's metadata).  Whether or not that actually happens depends on how the heap was implemented (which varies from one OS and compiler to the next) and what sort of corruption the fault introduced.

Comment: so shared_ptr::operator=(shared_ptr) is not threadsafe? This is the most confusing part for me. How will the shared_ptr know it is about to be copied and so will not release its memory even if its object count is 1?

Comment: According to the shared_ptr man page [ http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr ]:   "All member functions (including copy constructor and copy assignment) can be called by multiple threads on different instances of shared_ptr without additional synchronization even if these instances are copies and share ownership of the same object. If multiple threads of execution access the same shared_ptr without synchronization and any of those accesses uses a non-const member function of shared_ptr then a data race will occur"

Comment: ... since the shared_ptr assignment operator takes a (const shared_ptr & rhs) as its argument, then the way I read the above is that it should be thread safe to make a copy of the shared_ptr from another thread, since no non-const methods on rhs can be called.  (Of course that assumes that you can guarantee that rhs itself -- i.e. the shared_ptr object -- won't be destroyed during the assignment operation!)

Comment: But if they point to different objects? Because thread B is faster at updating its own shared_ptr and the one thread A has is an older object (from pov thread B), then the one in A will have ref_count 1 and the one in B will have ref_count 1, and there might be some overlap in time where A tries to update its own shared_ptr (which holds old data) while B is about to release it. Both having ref_count 1 means that they are essentially different objects right? Then this is not threadsafe?

Comment: As for how shared_ptr could implement this, my guess is that it is using atomic counters for the shared object's use-count.  The first thing thread A (the copying thread) would do in the assignment operator is increment-and-check the use-count.  If it's 1 after the increment, then thread B must have already released the object, and therefore the object isn't safe to use; in that case thread A's ptr can just set itself to NULL and we're done.  OTOH if it's >1 after the increment, then thread A is okay to read the object, because we know thread B won't drop it as long as thread A's count exists.

Answer (score 1):

Thread safety is an operation between threads, not an absolute in general.

You cannot read or write a variable while another thread writes a variable without synchronization between the other thread's write and your read or write.  Doing so is undefined behavior.

Undefined can mean anything.  Program crashes.  Program reads impossible value.  Program formats hard drive.  Program emails your browser history to all of your contacts.

A common case for unsynchronized integer access is that the compiler optimizes multiple reads to a value into one and doesn't reload it, because it can prove there is no defined way that someone could have modified the value.  Or, the CPU memory cache does the same thing, because you did not synchronize.

For the pointers, similar or worse problems can occur, including following dangling pointers, corrupting memory, crashes, etc.

[There are now atomic operations you can perform on shared pointers.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic), as well as [`atomic<shared_ptr<?>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic2).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Yakk, this helps a lot in informing me. Do you know if  copying a shared_ptr from another thread while the owning thread reassigns it (at that point ref_count = 1) is safe? I suspect not but I can't find  anything on this.